# Ubuntu 12.04 two graphics cards

Tags: graphics, video, multiple-monitors

I have been struggling to get my two graphics cards to work. One is on the board and one is not.

I can change the BIOS on my MSI motherboard to "Internal, PCI, or PCI-E".
Internal of course the one on the board becomes available. If I use PCI or PCI-E the card is used but the internal just doesn't show up at all on the system. With Windows installed "Internal" allows both to work.

Here is what I get when I do a `lspci`

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780L [Radeon HD 3000]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV516 [Radeon X1300/X1550 Series]
02:00.1 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV516 [Radeon X1300 Pro] (Secondary)
```

I'm not sure why the external, "X1300" is showing up twice.

I have tried to adjust the `xorg.conf` file which of course is not found initially but I guess I can't get it configured correct as it just crashes the OS or "X" anyway. I have two LG FLATRON W2061TQ monitors.

Any ideas on how to get both cards working with extended displays?

Answer (score 1):

After installed the second graphic card, I used this command to create new `xorg.conf` and it works.

```
sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial
```

After that if you want to move windows over the screens, enable the Xinerama.